# Authorization in GIT

Tags: git

I am new to Git. Is there any method in GIT to control the users from accessing the repository. I mean read only and all stuffs like that. I have installed the GUI and using that can I control the users by giving different access rights

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [git Permissioning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/96811/git-permissioning)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a server like

https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

There are ways to do that.

Comment: can we do it without installing gitolite . i mean only with git..and are there any limitations if we have only git..

Comment: I don't think it can